# Batch file - having trouble with searching and replacing function argument within a function

Tags: string, for-loop, batch-file, replace

I have the following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "ChosenFolder="
for /r /d %%f in (.) do call :function "%%f"
goto end

:function
echo %%~1:  %~1
set "ChosenFolder=!%~1:*\web\=!"
echo ChosenFolder:  %ChosenFolder%

:end
```

The batch file is located at `c:\docs\webs\my website name\web\`.  It is supposed to run through every subfolder and generate relative paths of each folder, stripping each path of everything up through `\web\`.  There are two total subfolders, `apples` and `apples\oranges`, so the output should look like this:

```
%~1:  c:\docs\webs\my website name\web\.
ChosenFolder:  \.
%~1:  c:\docs\webs\my website name\web\apples\.
ChosenFolder:  apples\.
%~1:  c:\docs\webs\my website name\web\apples\oranges\.
ChosenFolder:  apples\oranges\.
```

But instead, this is what I get:

```
%~1:  c:\docs\webs\my website name\web\.
ChosenFolder:  c:\docs\webs\my website name\web\.:*\web\=!
%~1:  c:\docs\webs\my website name\web\apples\.
ChosenFolder:  c:\docs\webs\my website name\web\apples\.:*\web\=!
%~1:  c:\docs\webs\my website name\web\apples\oranges\.:*\web\=!
ChosenFolder:  c:\docs\webs\my website name\web\apples\oranges\.:*\web\=!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please do not delete [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76019852), then repost it. We have an [Edit] link for you to use to bring a closed question up to the required standard. Lets say the first passed argument is `C:\docs\webs\my website name\web\apples\oranges`, then even with delayed expansion enabled, (which it isn't), you would have to have an existing variable named `C:\docs\webs\my website name\web\apples\oranges` for your idea to work, (and you haven't).

Comment: My apologies, I'll be sure to use the Edit feature in the future.  I have added delayed expansion, and I updated the question itself to be asking about "function argument" instead of "string variable."  I'm trying to assign the contents of the function parameter `%~1` to the ChosenFolder variable, minus path information leading up to `\web\`.  If this doesn't address the second part of your comment, then I guess I don't understand that part of your comment.

Comment: So sorry but I also made an error in the question originally in showing what the output *should* look like.  I now fixed this.  Also it seems my attempt to tag you in my comment did not work.  @Compo

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "ChosenFolder="
for %%e in (
"c:\docs\webs\my website name\web\."
"c:\docs\webs\my website name\web\apples\."
"c:\docs\webs\my website name\web\apples\oranges\."
) do call :function "%%~e"
goto end

:function
echo %%~1:  %~1
set "ChosenFolder=%~1"
SET "chosenfolder=%chosenfolder:*\web\=%"
echo ChosenFolder:  %ChosenFolder%

:end
```

Note: I used the directorynames you nominated in a simple `for` loop for testing, consequently the metavariable `%%e` is quoted and could be passed 'bare' or as I have shown, dequoted and quoted.

```
I prefer to avoid ADFNPSTXZ (in either case) as metavariables (loop-control variables) 
ADFNPSTXZ are also metavariable-modifiers which can lead to difficult-to-find bugs 
(See `for/f` from the prompt for documentation)
```

The problem with your code is that substringing only works on ordinary variables, not on metavariables.

Note also that `delayedexpansion` is not required unless you choose to use the single line

```
set "ChosenFolder=%~1"&SET "chosenfolder=!chosenfolder:*\web\=!"
```

Comment: Thank you @Magoo!  As always your responses are exceptionally helpful!